# Errors while Running the ZXING library in Eclipse

Tags: android, zxing

I'm trying to run ZXING library on my windows PC. I'm using Eclipse IDE. But when I open the project file in my eclipse it's showing me different errors(As shown in the this image

[image]

Although I'm following all the steps mentioned in this link [Getting Started with ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/GettingStarted) but when I try to build android it failed as shown in this image:

[image]

I need to deliver the project to my client. Please help or is there anyother barcode reader (I need UPC reader) library for Android available.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with zxing. You don't appear to understand how to use Eclipse, as you have not actually added zxing libraries to your project. I think you would need to take some time to get used to your IDE.

The second error is because Windows is not supported by the Proguard optimizer. Best is to get access to a Mac or Linux-based machine, since you do want to run the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

The zxing getting started is a bit confusing at times. Its not as easy as it seems to get started immediately. I faced similar issues and created a project for making it easy for the rest of the folks to follow.

Download http://www.4shared.com/file/bFx8Y5Ys/zXingJune2010.html. Let me know if you can not get it working.